# Open a .gz file and read/replace

Tags: php, gzip, fopen, fwrite

I can't find the answer I need, so I hope you understand what I'm after.

I need to be able to open a tar.gz file (from a remote website), read the files, and copy/replace these files on my website. I've been trying this code (as well as countless other codes):

```
$zipFile= 'http://awebsite.com/file.tar.gz';
$dir = 'myfolder';
$zp = @gzopen($zipFile, "r");
$fp = @fopen($dir, "w");
while(!@gzeof($zp)) {$string = @gzread($zp, 4096); @fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));}
@gzclose($zp);
@fclose($fp);
```

All seem to come up with errors of different sorts. I seem to be able to read the zip file, but not actually save the contents to my website.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Crito

Comment: Does `gzopen` allow you to open urls?

Comment: Yes, but you can't extract a tar file by writing it to a directory. That's just not how things work. :)

Comment: I can open it fine and read the entire contents line by line. But what I'm trying to do is get a list of the .php files within the zip file and save them to directory on my website.

Comment: @duskwuff, I've seen scripts that can do it 'somehow', I'm just not sure how. Wordpress uses a similar method. You can update your plugins and core version automatically. Something like that would be perfect.

Comment: It's possible, it just isn't that simple. You have to actually write a parser for the tar format, for instance.

Comment: A tar file is not a zip file.  It is a tar file.

Comment: Wow, I may be in 'over my head' here. I didn't think it was going to be as complicated as it looked. Is there any related articles somewhere that you recommend @duskwuff so that I can read about this process?

Comment: @Crito have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$zipFile= 'http://awebsite.com/file.tar.gz';
$dir = 'myfolder';
$zp = @gzopen($zipFile, "r");
$fp = @fopen("temp.tar", "w");
while(!@gzeof($zp)) {$string = @gzread($zp, 4096); @fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));}
@gzclose($zp);
@fclose($fp);
exec('tar xf temp.tar --overwrite --directory='.$dir);
?>
```

---

**Update:**

Here is a solution without using a temporary file and `tar` handles the gzip decompression itself:

```
<?php
$zipFile= 'http://awebsite.com/file.tar.gz';
$dir = 'myfolder';
$zp = @fopen($zipFile, "r");
$fp=popen('tar xzf - --overwrite --directory='.$dir,'w');
while(!@feof($zp)) {$string = @fread($zp, 4096); @fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));}
@fclose($zp);
@fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: It created the temp.rar file. But does not overwrite the files in the directory. Thanks for your help @stewe, it's a lot closer than I have gotten so far!

Comment: Check the file permissions (chmod), they must be writeable by the webserver/script. Also i hope `temp.rar` is a typo :)

Comment: Hmmm I had the folder set to write, but the files not. Can the files be chmod to writeable before update and back to non-writeable after? Would this cause a problem with this script @stewe?

Comment: It would work, but not from within the script, since is has no permissions to change the permissions :(
tar automatically tries that if it finds a [read-only](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32895) file for example. One solution would be to change the owner of the files to match the user executing the script. You can find out which user it is by using `echo exec('whoami');`

Comment: Because it replaces all files, I could unlink all the files in the folder first. I tested it and it worked fine. Thank you so much for your help on this @stewe.

Comment: You don't need to do the gunzipping, and you don't need to save a temporary tar file.  You can use subprocess (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to pipe the data directly into the tar command, which can invoke gunzip on its own.

Comment: No, you're piping data to a process on the same machine.

Comment: Sorry @MarkAdler, but this looks nothing like PHP to me and I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: For some reason I gave a link for python instead of php.  Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php .

Comment: @MarkAdler +1 added an example according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to decompressing, effectively removing the .gz suffix, you also need to interpret the tar file format, effectively removing the .tar suffix.  The easiest way to do that is to simply use the tar program itself.  Pipe what you are pulling to tar, running in the directory you want to update.  Read the tar man page to see the appropriate options for how you want to update the files.  (There are many choices.)